# Is it written litterature that deals with convergence of these random sums?

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, convergence-divergence, book-recommendation, weak-convergence

Let $\{w_i\}$ be a sequence of iid random variables, with $E[w_i]=0, V[w_i]=1$. Let $\{a_{i,N}\}_{i=1}^N$ be N real numbers that depend on N.

Let $s_N=\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^Na_{i,N}^2}$.

Is there any theory/books/proofs anywhere that deals with the convergence in distribution of

$\frac{1}{S_N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^Na_{i,N}w_i$?

The reason I am not able to use the ordinary central limit theorem, or Lindbergs CLT is that for each N the coefficients in front of $w_i$ changes.

Is there a standard way to deal with these sums? It seem likely that some work on this has been done, but I am not able to find it.

Comment: I'm probably going to say something completely off, but is there any hope of actually getting something at all? Take the following: for $N$ even, $a_{1,N}=a_{2,N}=1$, $a_{i,N}=0$ for $i>2$. For $N$ odd, all $a_{i,N}$'s are $0$, except $a_{1,N}=1$. Let $(w_i)'s$ be a sequence of iid Rademacher random variables, for instance. Then for $N$ odd, the sum is equal to $w_1$, and for $N$ odd it is $\frac{w_1+w_2}{\sqrt{2}}$: the distributions are different.

Comment: @ClementC. In order to get something useful I think we would need more conditions, maybe $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}s_n=\infty$ and more. One condition I am interested in is that we may have that $s_n$ is bounded, but each $a_{i,n}$ is positive, and increases with n. But I am not sure how I would prove or disprove that in this case we have convergence to $N(0,1)$. In this case we would get a contribution from infinitely many independent $w_i$, so I guess it is not entirely implausible that we do not have convergence to $N(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Please put your problems in the regime of triangle array of RVs,(c.f. P. Billingsley, *Probability and Measures*, Anniversary Ed., J. Wiley & Sons Inc.(2001), Sec27.6--), then you can verify that the Lindeberg condition is satisfied if the following limit holds
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\max_{1\le i\le n}|a_{n,i}|}{s_n}=0. \tag{1} $$
Therefore, you could get CLT under (1).